# How to determine why Mathematica killed an evaluation and cleared all variables?

Tags: equation-solving, kernel

I am curious if Mathematica stores a system log somewhere or if there is a way to set up my notebook such that it details why Mathematica silently kills an evaluation and clears all variables in the notebook.

For context, my problem is that I have a very large expression `f[a,b,c,d,...]` for which I am asking Mathematica to solve in terms of one variable:

> sol = Solve[f[a,b,c,d,...]==0,b]

The notebook will state it is running for about 30 minutes, and then Mathematica silently terminates the evaluation and clears the variables.

Comment: Could it be a memory overflow?

Comment: Usually for me this happens when the kernel crashes as it run out of memory etc, so check your memory consumption, eg with the Task Manager on Windows.

Comment: Also, if you have a concrete example in mind, please post the relevant code, along with info on the OS and mathematica version :-)

Comment: Mathematica keeps a history of all calculations which use up memory.  One way to avoid this is to use `$HistoryLength=0` at start of notebook or in an Initialization group.

Comment: Just to confirm, this is almost certainly a kernel crash. As to why, impossible to say without testing the input. Out of memory would be the prime suspect though, as @HansOlo suggests.

Comment: As suggested, it sounds like Mathematica is running out of memory.  In my experience, when `Solve` takes a long time it is unlikely to return anything useful.  I would suggest that you need to simplify your problem before applying `Solve`.  For example, you could substitute numerical values for some parameters.  These will give you (relatively quickly) an idea of whether this is a problem Mathematica can deal with.  If you post the expression you are trying to solve, you may get useful advice.

Comment: If an inexact answer would suffice, it might be worthwhile to try to rephrase your `Solve` problem as an optimization problem and try it with `NMinimize`, especially if you can make a relatively smooth objective function out of it. But we would need more details to make any detailed suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. It sounds like the answer to my question is that there is no way within Mathematica (like a system log) to determine why it terminates an evaluation. However, as suggested, I monitored the memory consumption during evaluation and it does seem to be running out of memory. I was already using `$HistoryLength=0`, symbolic parameters, and had applied `FullSimplify` to the expression in a previous notebook and that did not help. I will continue exploring other avenues. Thank you again.